# React - calling a function in parent component to access state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was trying to build a simple calculator application to get started with React. I was trying to call a function in root component from the child one so as to access the current state. I was able to call the function but I can not access the state as i want update the state . Below is my code :

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
            numbers: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            actions: ['=','+','-','*','/','.','C']
        }
    }


    appendThisNumber(number,oldcount){
        let newCount=parseInt(oldcount.toString()+number.toString()); 
        console.log('New number '+newCount);
        //below code errors out 
        this.setState({
            count:newCount 
        });

    };
    performThisAction(action, oldcount){
        // stuff to do
    };
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <CounterDiv countNow={this.state.count} />
                <div>
                    {this.state.numbers.map((n) => <NumButton NumValue={n} countNow={this.state.count} onClickFunction={this.appendThisNumber}/>)}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {this.state.actions.map((a) => <ActionButtons actionItem={a} countNow={this.state.count} onClickFunction={this.performThisAction}/>)}
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}


class CounterDiv extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='text' readOnly value={this.props.countNow} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class NumButton extends React.Component {
    handleClick(){
        this.props.onClickFunction(this.props.NumValue,this.props.countNow);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick()} value={this.props.NumValue}>{this.props.NumValue}</button>
        );
    }
}

class ActionButtons extends React.Component{
    handleClick(){
        this.props.onClickFunction(this.props.actionItem,this.props.countNow);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick()} value={this.props.actionItem} label={this.props.actionItem}>{this.props.actionItem}</button>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong or do I need to use some data binding framework for it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: either use arrow function or bind this to function

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala did the binding ,that worked .But whenever I define an arrow function it throws some exception. thats why I have defined all the functions with names like addThisNumber (){..} instead of addThisNumber= () =>{..}  . Why? Does it have something to do with the version of react i am using ("react": "^16.4.1","react-dom": "^16.4.1") or something else? Thanks

Comment: can you post that exception? the version is not the problem m sure

Comment: Here it is :  App.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:/Users/SsJoshi/Desktop/React/App.jsx: Unexpected token (14:10)

  12 |     }
  13 | 
> 14 |     addOne= () =>{
     |           ^
  15 |         this.setState({
  16 |             count: this.state.count + 1
  17 |         });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your `appendThisNumber()` to `this`.

Bind it in your constructor as:

```
 this.appendThisNumber = this.appendThisNumber.bind(this);
```

Comment: It worked thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `bind` the function in your class to do so :

```
  class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
+     this.appendThisNumber = this.appendThisNumber.bind(this);
      this.state = {
          count: 0,
          numbers: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
          actions: ['=','+','-','*','/','.','C']
      }
  }
```

See [the official doc on "Handling events"](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for more informations

Comment: Yes it works ! +1 for the readout link :)